# How to get the data type in Typescript using Generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a data structure that is built using generics.  When I go to populate data though, I want to ensure I can convert some simple formats into the proper types.  As the class us configured using Generics, I cannot seem to detect the type of the data in other code.

This is a simple example extracted from my code:

```
export class Field<T> {
    private Name_: string;
    private Value_: T;

    constructor(FieldName:string, Data?:T) {
        this.Name_ = FieldName;
        if( Data !== undefined) {
            this.Value_ = Data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the data value from this class
     * @returns T The value from Value_
     */
    get Value(): T {
        return this.Value_;
    }

    get Type(): string {
        return typeof this.Value_;
    }

    /**
     * Set the data into the data value
     * @param Data T Generic Data member as the raw data to be stored in the field.
     */
    set Value(Data:T) {
        this.Value_ = Data;
    }
}
```

This is a simple code snippet to demonstrate the problem.  My structure (Field) is defined with a generic (Field) and I expect the value in the data to be of that type.

I am trying to test this but I cannot get the type from the Object (as it is of type Field), so I was trying to get the type of the internal data field.

```
    describe('Get Type of Value', () => {
        let TestField:Field<number> = new Field<number>('Age', 32);
        it('should return the value type from the definition', () => {
            expect(TestField.Type).toBe('number');
        });
    });
```

The test fails indicating that the Type getter function returns undefined.

```
 FAIL  
    Expected value to be (using Object.is):
      "number"
    Received:
      "undefined"
```

Comment: When I run this code (`let TestField: Field<number>`) I get a TypeScript error that string is not assignable to number

Comment: Sorry, it was an editing error in creating example.  I have updated the new to be Field<number>('Age', 32); so it will pass Typescript compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine:

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Field%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20Name_%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20Value_%3A%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(FieldName%3Astring%2C%20Data%3F%3AT)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Name_%20%3D%20FieldName%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(%20Data%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Value_%20%3D%20Data%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Get%20the%20data%20value%20from%20this%20class%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40returns%20T%20The%20value%20from%20Value_%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20get%20Value()%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.Value_%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20Type()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20this.Value_%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Set%20the%20data%20into%20the%20data%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40param%20Data%20T%20Generic%20Data%20member%20as%20the%20raw%20data%20to%20be%20stored%20in%20the%20field.%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20set%20Value(Data%3AT)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Value_%20%3D%20Data%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20TestField%3A%20Field%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20new%20Field%3Cnumber%3E('Age'%2C%2032)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(TestField.Value)%0Aconsole.log(TestField.Type))

I suspect your test runner (Jest?) is doing something funky. Move the `let TestField...` inside `it('...', () => { /* here */ })` and try again.

By the way, per general convention of JavaScript, your variables and properties should be camel case

Comment: Our coding standard has ProperCase, which is why the variables are like they are, to help identify our code and functions from standard library and external modules.

Comment: I did check your sample, it does appear to work, but Jest has a problem, even with the variable assignment in the it() block.

Comment: That's strange, I don't see other reasons that it can fail.

Comment: I used your TypeScript Playground and can see the debug working.  However, the Jest gets an undefined coming back.  Other things seem to work correctly, just this piece.

Comment: The value field was not assigned in the test. When I match the constructor parameters with what was passed, values were not sent, hence undefined is the correct response.